# How many times this loop will run?

Tags: c, loops, memory

Interview asked question:

```
while(1)
{
void * a = malloc(1024*1024); 
}
```

How many times this loop will run on a `2 gb` ram and a `8 gb` ram ?

I said  infinite loop because there is no terminating condition even if memory will be full.
He din't agree.I don't have any idea now.Please help.

Comment: @Nobilis If memory is full, `malloc()` returns `NULL`.

Comment: @H2CO3 Yeah I thought about it and actually there's not guarantee it will segfault as the malloc call will just keep returning NULL, removed comment.

Comment: it's a good thing you didn't get that job then :)

Comment: Good question ran this on a visual studio on win 7 system and it almost crashed my system .My computer  froze for like 5 minutes and i had to hard shutdown and restart  to get back here  :) .

Comment: That's a really obtuse interview question. It only looks to see if you are some kind of wizard. Nobody would ever create a loop like that. I hope the job itself was actually relevant to that. It makes far more sense to stick to questions that are relevant.

Comment: @H2CO3 Are you sure, aren't the words *"full"* and *"NULL"* pronounced entirely different?

Comment: @ChristianRau I'm not a native English speaker, but AFAIK they are pronounced very similarly.

Comment: @H2CO3: In southern England, I'd expect to hear _null_ pronounced quite differently from _full_; in northern England, I could believe _null_ could be pronounced like _full_ (though I've not heard pronounced like that).  The (British) dictionary on Mac specifies 'null |nʌl|' and 'full |fʊl|', where the vowel mark in the pronunciation is quite different between the two.  The (American) dictionary is different again: 'null |nəl|' versus 'full |fo͝ol|' but the words are clearly pronounced differently in American as well as in English.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I flagged this comment for migration to English.SE. JK, thanks for the explanation! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It should run indefinitely.  On most platforms, when there's no more memory available, `malloc()` will return 0, so the loop will keep on running without changing the amount of memory allocated.  Linux allows memory over-commitment so that `malloc()` calls continue to add to virtual memory.  The process might eventually get killed by the OOM Killer when the data that `malloc()` uses to administer the memory starts to cause problems (it won't be because you try using the allocated memory itself because the code doesn't use it), but Linux isn't stipulated as the platform in the question.

Comment: OOM killer will only get into action as soon as the memory is really used. As long as I keep the memory I allocated unwritten to, nothing should happen.

Comment: Hm, I was wrong. With 1 MiB malloc size, the administration data become so large that they eventually fill up the memory on a 64 bit system. With 1 GiB malloc size, the virtual memory size gets suck at 107t (according to `top`) and the program runs indefinitely.

Comment: @glglgl: yes — but you might reach a point where `malloc()` has to write to memory to maintain its lists of what it has allocated, and at that point the OOM Killer might swing into action.

Comment: And sir suppose if we are not talking about Linux then? Take any old compiler like turbo c/c++ ?

Comment: @joeyrohan In *that* old compiler you'll definitely get `NULL` at some point, making the loop indeed endless.

Comment: @glglgl: interesting — I wonder why the virtual memory sticks at 107 TiB...it smacks a bit of a bug, but I'm not sure that it is a practical bug; I believe there are few machines with terabytes of main memory at the moment.

Comment: And on a 32 bit system I get "to the `NULL` stage" with 1 MiB allocation as well. Very soon.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Perhaps `malloc` truly fails at that point because it cannot allocate any more space for administrative purposes.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The pointers are 6 bytes long, i.e. 48 bits. That should be enough for 256 TiB; if I limit myself to <7fffffffffff, for 128 TiB. At some point the `mmap()` ceased to be successfull and the "regular" heap was used. There is a gap between 2b8c814d1000 (end of heap) and 3f350c000000 (start of mmap area) as well as between 7f35213e7000 (end of mmap area) and 7fffaef10000 (start of stack). Obviously the allocation purpose between these memory areas is very strict.

Comment: And if I change the program to halve the size for `malloc()`, I even get close to "127t" in top.